# Difference between C++ const references and consts?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, lvalue, rvalue

What is the difference between:

```
const double& pi = 3.14;
```

and (no ampersand):

```
const double pi = 3.14;
```

They both seem to have the same L and R values so what is the difference?

Comment: Do you know the difference between a non-reference and reference?

Comment: Yes I understand for non consts the difference between a variable and a reference, it is just when they are const that that they seem to have the same behaviour. Is there any way to tell them apart when they are const?

Comment: The `const` makes no difference, references don't have the same behavior as non-references. Maybe in *this case*, but surely you use them in other situations?

Comment: Yes I was just talking about in this particular situation with consts. I know references are totally different from non refs when non constant but when a constant ref is created, it's associated value cannot be changed which seemed not to be different from using a non reference variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your particular example there's no difference.

And that means, no way to tell them apart, whatsoever.

However, since the first binds a reference to a temporary, when the type is of class type the temporary can be of a derived class, e.g. produced by a function! And it then has its destructor properly called at the end of the scope. This little el neato trick is used in ScopeGuard implementations (see the original [ScopeGuard article in DDJ](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403758), by Petru Marginean and Andrei Alexandrescu -- Petru invented ScopeGuard and Andrei made a more general thing on top).

I once asked Bjarne Stroustrup, who created the C++ language, why the syntax in your first declaration is supported.

And his reply was that it was mostly to have uniform rules (i.e. to not make any special exception for local references as opposed to references as formal parameters). I think at that time neither of us were familiar with ScopeGuard. It's simple in retrospect, but it takes a mind like Petru's, or Andrei's, to come up with something like that! :-)

Cheers & hth.

Comment: Great answer. Just wanted to ask, in what sense is the first one "temporary", as in what exactly does this mean? How is it different to the second? Thanks.

Comment: A reference is just a reference to something else. You can think it as just an alias. But internally the compiler can implement it as a pointer, like, you write `int const& x = 42`, and the compiler may (conceptually) translate that to `int const __blah = 42; int const* const x = &__blah;`. Or, it might optimize the whole thing away... But the formal rule for binding a reference to an rvalue is that a temporary is created, and the reference is set to refer to that temporary. The rules for the more general case differ a little between C++98 and C++0x, but roughly, that's it.

Comment: "And that means, no way to tell them apart, whatsoever.", don't forget C++0x' decltype, and that a const reference isn't an integral constant expression. I dunno a way to get a valid C++03 program to print "ref" or "nonref", given the above two variables and applied to the one or the other, though. C++0x wasn't asked about, but I thought I would just throw it in.

Comment: @Johannes: Great comment! I have my literal words still standing, but if the type is changed to say `int` then one can tell them apart by a program using `int const x` compiling OK, while using `int const& y` it doesn't compile (say, using those as array size). So I should perhaps have written "There's no way the choice of one or the other can influence the effect of a valid program", which sidesteps the issue of whether the code compiles. :-) As I understand it you're leaning towards the same opinion but not quite sure. But it's been discussed repeatedly, no known counter-example. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The important difference with a reference is that a reference itself is inheritly constant. Once the reference itself has been initially assigned to a variable, it can not then reference another variable. All attempts to modify it will modify the variable it refers to. Given this, the `const` will mean that the reference is a reference to a `const int`.

```
const int A;
const int B;
const int& Reference = A;
Reference = B; // Error, the value of A can not be assigned, nor would this *ever* be able to make Reference refer to B.
```

You can also test this theory about a reference itself being constant like so:

```
const int& const Reference; // Should give a warning about the second const being redundant.
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of clarification about constant references, references and constants for `double`s.

### Reference

A reference refers to an existing an object and cannot be *reseated.*  That is, once you declare (define) the reference, it will always refer to that item.

### Constant Reference

The C++ language allows for declaring of a constant reference.  This tells the compiler that the reference will not change.  This may be redundant since references cannot be reseated.  However, the language syntax allows it.

### Constant

A constant is a value, and does not **refer** to anything.

### Optimizations & Substitutions

The compiler is allowed to substitute (replace) a reference to an object, constant or literal with the corresponding object, constant or literal, provided that the compiler can guarantee that no write operations are performed to that object within the scope it is used in.  This determination may become difficult when the reference is passed to methods or functions within that scope.

Specifying the `const` modifier to a reference will make the compiler's job easier for optimizing.  The constant reference is a contract with the programmer and user that the reference will not be changed.

Comment: Would the following be allowed then:    double& pi = 3.14    or would you have to use const to reference a pure value such as 3.14?

Answer (score 0):

const double& is a reference to a constant double, the other one is a constant double. A reference is kind of a const pointer, a pointer that never changes.

Comment: Yes but are they functionally any different? That is, for non const you can tell int& and int values apart but is it possible to tell const int& and const int apart? Do they ever behave differently in terms of function or performance?

Comment: Regarding performance passing by value is really expensive when passing big objects, that's why you want reference. Regarding const int there's no real reason to use references when passing to functions, sometimes int is smaller. Functionally a reference isn't an actual int, it's a reference to another int. But you can use them similarly.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the references are inherently const. Once they have been assigned you can not changes them. They must be both declared and initialized.

Answer (score -3):

The reference isnt const only the value is const, so you should be able reassign referense, that means the following would be ok:

```
const double& pi = 3.14;
const double  pi2 = 2.78;
pi = *(&pi2);
```

Comment: Mm, nope. References cannot be reseated. This tries to assign a value to a const variable, and is ill-formed.

Comment: maybe like this:
pi = *(&pi2);   ?

Comment: @Adesit: What? What difference would that make? `*&` cancels out. You cannot reseat a reference, you cannot assign to a const variable.

Comment: i dont want assign a variable but reassign a ref. Well i admit, its just a fast guess. I didnt compile.

Comment: You can't "reassign" a reference. It is inherently constant. Once "assigned" it can never be "reassigned". Also, there is no point to taking the address of `pi2` and then dereferencing it. I'm not even sure you can initialize a reference to a literal, as the literal is not a variable.

Comment: @Adesit: Like I've said twice, you cannot reseat a reference.  @Sion: It creates a temporary and binds to it.